# Modify Hard Coded Path in the Dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a library DLL which is saving the output files to D Drive (HardCoded Path in the library )
The application crashes if the user doesnt have the drive in the pc.

Can we do anything so the DLL starts saving into the desired path instead of HardCoded 
One solution was to insert a pendrive and Label it D: It works but this is not a good solution

Any Suggestion\Solutions will be greatly appreciated

P.S. The DLL is Written in C# .
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you don't have access to the source code, a symlink maybe?

Comment: @Diado could you make that an answer, including explaining what a symlink is?

Comment: do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit the original library to change the path to something more suitable, or even change the method more extensively, you can use [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases).

In the decompiled code navigate to the method where the value is hardcoded and in the context menu click on `Edit Method` and perform the changes.

[image]

[image]

Then go to `File-> Save Module...` to save the edited assembly.

You can also use `dnSpy` to debug the crashing application to find the exact spot where the exception occurs.

Depending on things such as version and obfuscation, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

In my comment I suggested using a symlink (or *Symbolic Link*), but on reflection that would only work if the D drive exists - i.e. you could redirect a non-existent folder on the D drive to one that does exist on the C drive, as long as the D drive exists.

There is another alternative though - the [SUBST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) command. SUBST associates a drive letter with a path. For instance:

```
subst d: c:\MyRealFolder
```

The above will redirect requests for the `D` drive to the `MyRealFolder` folder on the `C` drive.